# How does one express the decrease in minimal type II error bound for each observation added?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler, information-theory, bounds

**Problem**: I have a "classifier" that uses some arbitrary hypothesis test on observations from one of two known probability distributions:

1. $P_0$ (null hypothesis $H_0$) is a zero-mean Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_0^2)$
2. $P_1$ (alternate hypothesis $H_1$) is a mixture of the zero-mean Gaussian from $P_0$ and some other zero-mean Gaussian with a higher variance $p\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_0^2)+(1-p)\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)$ where $\sigma_0^2<\sigma_1^2$

The parameters $\sigma_0^2$, $\sigma_1^2$, and $p$ are assumed to be known. Think of it as testing a machine.  $H_0$ means that the machine is operating in good state, and $H_1$ means that the machine needs service.

The "classifier" is allowed some fixed Type I Error $\alpha$.  I am interested in determining how the *lower* bound on Type II Error $\beta$ behaves as I use more observations.  Specifically, I am interested in how the lower bound on $\beta$ decreases for each additional observation.  Reason for this is that there is cost per each observation I make.

**Question**: I am trying to find how much I can lower the *lower* bound on $\beta$ with each additional observation, and knowing the parameters $\sigma_0^2$, $\sigma_1^2$, and $p$ of the distributions being tested.  Can it be related to the sum of errors for a *single* observation?

**Prior knowledge**:  For a single observation, I know that I can bound the sum of errors $\alpha+\beta\geq 1-TV(P_0,P_1)$ where $TV$ is [total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) per [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72721/what-is-the-relationship-of-mathcall-1-total-variation-distance-to-hypoth) I asked at math.SE.  The total variation between the two distributions in my problem is actually quite nice, as it's just $pTV(\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_0^2),\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2))$.  I also know that I can upper-bound $TV$ by the square root of half of [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) using [Pinsker's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality) (there are additional benefits to using KL bound which are out of scope of this question...)  However, I do not know how to relate the bound on one observation to lowering of the bound with an additional observation.

**My mathematical sophistication**: I have graduate-level background in probability theory (the M.S. Engineering course).  I also have graduate-level background in information theory and signal theory.  Unfortunately, I have very limited knowledge of measure theory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the sample size the following way. You need to understand the use of product measure in mathematical statistics.

You observe $X_1,\dots,X_n$ iid from $P_i$ ($i=0$ or $i=1$). This can be rephrased by: you observe ${\bf P_i}=P_i\otimes  P_i \otimes \dots \otimes P_i=P_i^{\otimes n}$, where $\nu \otimes \mu$ is the **[product measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure)** obtained from $\nu$ and $\mu$.

Now $KL({\bf P_0},{\bf P_1})=n  KL( P_0, P_1)$. I am sure you can easily get a result from that. Now if you are trying to work directlky with the TV distance (which is an idea, but certainly unpractical from my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17300/hypothesis-testing-and-total-variation-distance-vs-kullback-leibler-divergence/17315#17315)), the thing you should try to evaluate (or upper bound) is:

$2*TV({\bf P_0},{\bf P_1})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Pi_{j=1}^n\phi_1(x_j)-\Pi_{j=1}^n\phi_0(x_j)|dx_1\dots, dx_n$ (for $i=0,1$ $\phi_i$ density of $P_i$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I have tried the KL bound on the product measure:

$$\begin{align}2TV(\mathbf{P_0},\mathbf{P_1})&\leq& \sqrt{nKL(P_0,P_1)}\\
&\leq&\sqrt{npKL\left(\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_0^2),\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)\right)}\end{align}$$

with the second line from using [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) (and apologies for the abuse of notation).  Unfortunately, that bound is not tight enough. (continued...)

Comment: I've also gotten a bound in form of 

$$\sqrt{nKL(P_0,P_1)}\leq p\left(\frac{n\left(\sigma_0-\sqrt{2\sigma_0^2-\sigma_1^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\sigma_0^2-\sigma_1^2}}\right)^{1/2}$$ 

using 2 degree Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{nKL(P_0,P_1)}$, which is better for small $p$ (which is the case here) and $2\sigma_0^2>\sigma_1^2$ (I can live with that).  However, some of my experiments suggest the following upper bound:

$$p\sqrt{n\log(\sigma_0^2/\sigma_1^2)}$$

but I have not idea how to get it analytically...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Allright, I am satisfied with the KL-based bounds I found.  Thank you for your help, @robin girard!