# Is the Neyman-Pearson paradigm for hypothesis testing adequate in the social sciences, and if not, is calculating a priori power still adequate?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, statistical-power, effect-size

I'm reading about Fisherian vs. Neyman-Pearson paradigms relative to hypothesis/significance testing. (NB: I'm new to this and self-studying it, so I'd be glad to be corrected if I misinterpret concepts or misuse words.)

In [this article](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/16557/1/Rubin%20%282019%29%20-%20What%20Type%20of%20Type%20I%20Error.pdf) (pdf file), the author argues that the Neyman-Pearson paradigm is less adequate in the social sciences than the Fisherian paradigm, because the population is changing constantly -so you can't conduct exact replications of a study, but exact replications are an assumption of Neyman-Pearson.

Assuming the author is right (I don't know if he is), then does it still make sense to compute sample sizes if we are in another paradigm (Fisherian, Bayesian, or others I may not know)?

Let's say I'm interested in detecting some minimal effect size of interest in the sample I collect (if this effect exists in the "temporary" population of interest), what are my options outside Neyman-Pearson? (given that exact replications on the long run in the real world are impossible).

Comment: Welcome to CV. Your link to the pdf is not working. In general though, the validity of the N-P approach does not rely on actual replications of the _same_ experiment. Replications can be hypothetical or the long run involved can be across independent different experiments.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt strange, the link works for me. Here is an alternative link:  https://philpapers.org/archive/RUBWTO (if this one does not work either, the title is "What type of Type I error? Contrasting the Neyman–Pearson and Fisherian approaches in the context of exact and direct replications" if you want to google it). In the paper, page 16 (mid-page), the author gives an example of real-life direct (not *exact*) replications under the NP paradigm, example which failed.

Comment: The calculations of sample sizes under the two paradigms (NP and Fisher) use exactly the same mathematical models and yield exactly the same results. Because a Bayesian procedure differs mathematically, it might come up with a different sample size.  (It really ought to when the researcher adopts a strong prior distribution, because that is giving information equivalent to a preliminary sample and so the computed sample size ought to be lower in such cases.) In the end, how you compute sample sizes depends on how you intend to analyze the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubin, the author of the linked paper, is probably correct in saying that the Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis testing approach is inferior to a Fisherian significance testing approach for most scientific purposes (social science or otherwise). He is also correct in pointing out that the long-run series of exact replications of an experiment imagined by Neyman as a justification of the error rates is impossible in many real-world circumstances. (I'm not sure that the justification requires more than an imaginary series, however.)

However, I think that the coining of the term "Fisherian sample-specific type I error probability" is unfortunate. I'm pretty sure that Fisher did not ever adopt the term "type I error" for any description of the result of his significance testing. Certainly he argued against the idea that a p-value could be used as a probability statement linked to the null hypothesis, and that would preclude its use as a type I error rate:

> It [the p-value] is more primitive, or elemental than, and does not justify, any exact probability statement about the proposition [the null hypothesis]. (Fisher, 1956)

Instead of calling the p-value an error probability it is more helpful, in my opinion, to call it an index of evidence. That allows the distinction between evidence and error rates to be clear (Lew, 2020).

Now, your question boils down to one of how to determine sample size. You can do what is commonly done and use a sample size that seems reasonable, taking effort and cost into account, and then post-hoc set up a sample size calculation to yield that size by adjusting the 'expected' effect size to suit. (No, don't do that!)

The Neyman–Pearsonian error rate paradigm has limited utility in the analysis of the results scientific experiments, but that does not mean that it is not useful *before* the experiment. You suggest that you have in mind a minimal effect size of interest, so plug that in to a power calculation routine and determine the sample size needed for an acceptable power. (Then increase the sample size a bit to take into account the miss-match between the statistical model and the real world data generating and sampling mechanisms...) Such Neyman–Pearsonian planning does not affect the Fisherian interpretation of the experimental results in any way. Nothing that you do before the data are obtained alters the evidential meaning of the data.

There are a couple of alternative views of the pre-experiment power analysis that are worth consideration. One plots the power against effect size for any sample size, and another plots the expected p-value against effect size. Either or both will improve your intuitions regarding experimental power and sample size planning. See section 2.5 in Lew, 2020.

1. Fisher, R.A. 1956 Statistical Methods and Scientific Inference, 1956. p.46 in the Oxford Science Publications reprint of 2003.
2. Lew, M.J. 2020 [A Reckless Guide to P-values: local evidence and global errors](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286)

Comment: Your answer and the comment by whuber makes things much clearer and reassuring to me. Thank you both.

Comment: @Coris Further to whuber's comment, a famous article by Lehmann demonstrates the similarity between the Fisher and Neyman-Pearson testing methods. It can be found via  another answer : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/192098/343075

Comment: @GrahamBornholt Yes, that's an interesting article, but to me it reads more as an attempt to reconcile the unreconcilable. It does not seem to me to be a correct representation of Fisher's approach and instead casts Fisherian analysis in terms of fixed levels of alpha rather than graded levels of p-values. A famous paper, perhaps, but not one that I would go to.

Comment: I did not think it went quite that far. Fisher did not fix alpha level before hand but at times he did find p-values below 5% and 1% particularly interesting. In contrast, Neyman-Pearson fixed alpha levels for their optimisations but what the fixed values were depended on the specific problem. However, people now believe 5% and 1% were Neyman-Pearson's idea.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt Fisher found 5% and 1% interesting but in large part because he was working from tables of critical values or test statistics rather than exact p-values. He did say that anyone using 5% would not be too often wrong, but that was in the context of work where interesting results were followed up upon with repeated experimentation. He never approved of the one-and-done type of 'significant' that comes from Neyman and Pearson. See here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3419900/ and here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286 for my take on the issues.

Comment: @Micheal Lew Interestingly, Neyman-Pearson also used 1% and 5% because of Fisher's tables! Thanks for the references to your papers. I have read the first one. The surprise was the the description of the Neyman-Pearson tester in Example 2. Perhaps you are right in the claim that Neyman Pearson rejections are final, with experiments never to be repeated after just one sample. If so, I am confident that there are no scientists following the Neyman-Pearson method literally in this regard  (probably neither Neyman or Pearson did either). All conclusions in statistics are provisional. ctd

Comment: I find the Cox and Hinkley 1974 book "Theoretical Statistics" is an excellent reference book for significance testing. Cox's 1958 paper long ago made the point that statistical inference is only a part, sometimes a small part, of scientific inference, and his warning is as apt today as it was then. Cox was a Fisherian in most things (as am I).

Comment: @MichaelLew Just finished your chapter. Very nice article.