How would RA Fisher (or "a Fisherian") choose sample sizes?
As noted in many other CV.SE posts such as here or here, there are differences in practice and interpretation between RA Fisher's and Neyman & Pearson's frameworks for statistical hypothesis testing.
I am curious about their differences in how to design your study. To keep it simple, I'll focus on sample size (but of course power and precision are also affected by other aspects of study design such as blocking etc.).
Under the N-P framework, the general approach is clear to me: First decide the power you want, the specific alternative point hypothesis $H_A$ you are interested in (for instance, in terms of the smallest effect size you care to detect), and the Type I error rate $\alpha$ you will tolerate. From there you can work out the sample size needed to achieve your desired power for that $\alpha$ and $H_A$.
But as I understand it, in a Fisherian approach there is no $\alpha$, no $H_A$, and no explicit power calculation. So how did Fisher choose sample sizes for his own studies? (Or how did he advise others to plan their sample sizes?)

I am curious especially because Fisher did write about "a properly designed experiment" being one that usually gives a low p-value.

Personally, the writer prefers to set a low standard of significance at the 5 per cent. point, and ignore entirely all results which fail to reach this level. A scientific fact should be regarded as experimentally established only if a properly designed experiment rarely fails to give this level of significance.

-- Fisher, R. A. The arrangement of field experiments. Journal of the Ministry of Agriculture, 1926, 33, p.504.
To me, this 1926 quote (especially "rarely fails") sounds quite similar to saying a well-designed experiment should have high power: although he didn't specify a particular $H_A$, Fisher imagines repeating the same experiment with the same design on the same population (though in this quote it's ambiguous whether these repetitions are hypothetical or should actually be carried out), and repeatedly getting results at or below the 5 % significance level.
If Fisher was OK with setting a significance level, and Fisher was on board with aiming for high power -- then what else could he do to choose a sample size to achieve these things, while being substantially different from N-P's overall approach?
(Of course there are Bayesian, Likelihoodist, and perhaps other non-Fisherian and non-NP approaches. But I'm specifically asking about what would count as Fisherian yet non-NP.)

Possibly the words are getting in the way of understanding what Fisher intended.  Consider reading "rarely fails to give [5%] significance" as "has at least 95% power at an implicit effect size."

To my recollection he used sensitivity with much the same meaning, though I don't recall his trying to quantify it. It may be relevant to note that in much of his writing on experiments, random assignment to treatments is the basis for statistical inference. i.e. a non-parametric framework. The famous tea-tasting experiment in The Design of Experiments is a good example..

@whuber Thank you but I'm afraid I don't follow. Are you suggesting that Fisher's "5%" in that quote is one minus the power? I'm pretty sure his "5%" here is (what today we'd call) the alpha level under a null hypothesis of no difference -- which is entirely different from 1 - power. In that 1926 paper, Fisher's writing about a difference in means between treatment & control, and his "5% point" is a difference-in-sample-means so large that it would be seen very rarely (no more than 5% of the time) in control-vs-control comparisons.

But I do agree that Fisher, Neyman, Pearson, and others used the same language in incompatible ways sometimes, and that's surely contributed to the widespread confusion over the differences between their frameworks!

Good question, but may take historical research to answer. Here are some thoughts:  1) In my linked answer, I write, "Allegedly, a researcher once approached Fisher with 'non-significant' results, asking him what he should do, and Fisher said, 'go get more data'." I have heard this several times, but it could be apocryphal. 2) The idea of power was known earlier, but I don't think people worried about it before it was popularized in the '60 & '70s. 3) The problem w/ running a study until it's significant isn't hard to intuit, but I don't know people were worried about it until much later.

Another issue is that the traditional power analysis / experimental design process assumes you can just get more patients--as many as you may need.  That isn't necessarily the case (eg, w/ a rare disease).  Fisher primarily worked w/ agricultural research where treatments were applied to fields.  I wouldn't assume they could just say, 'we need 40 extra fields for adequate power, go get some more'.  OTOH, he did develop the split plot as a way to enhance power.

Directly related, possibly a duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/620477/164936

@J-J-J Thanks but I think these are distinct questions. That one asks for best practices: is N-P power analysis still ok, and what else could be done in general (incl Bayesian or other views)? I am asking about history: what did Fisher himself recommend, and how did it differ from N-P power analysis?

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thank you, I just found a copy of TDoE (8th ed) and you are right! Would you post your comment as an answer? He introduces (but doesn't rigorously define) "the sensitiveness of an experiment" on p.21-22 and describes what sounds to me like power curves, either with respect to increasing sample size or w.r.t. repeating the experiment many times. So maybe he wasn't actually against power calc in principle, just against N-P personally (and also just did more papers on qualitative changes to designs, eg blocking, than on quantitative choice of sample size).

@civilstat Agreed. I had doubts, and the scope is indeed different. To clarify, I wasn't suggesting closing your question in favor of the other, but rather the other way around, as your question seemed broader to me.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica On reflection, "sensitiveness" may not be the same as power. Fisher's example is about increasing n to allow for more mistakes by the lady tasting tea and still reach significance -- so he's allowing a larger range of statistics to count as evidence against $H_0$, without ever specifying an alternative parameter value / $H_A$. Jose Perezgonzalez has written about "sensitiveness" but it's not clear to me whether it's the same as Fisher's, esp. since Fisher didn't give an explicit definition. Still, your comment is closest to what I had in mind!

What I wanted to get at, though, is that F. introduces no statistical model of gradations in the subject's ability to discriminate; so there's no question of calculating the power of his test when any particular alternative hypothesis to 'no ability whatsoever' is true, except 'an infallible ability'. Indeed it's hard to see why we should place much trust in any such model when we're at the stage of wondering whether the phenomenon even exists; & the analysis also nicely illustrates his assertion that researchers can often be quite sure that their test statistic adequately ...

... measures discrepancy with the null while having only a foggy notion of alternatives. (By the way, despite his going into considerable detail on experimental protocol, F. makes no mention of whether the subject has to pronounce her judgements one by one after tasting each cup, or is allowed to taste all cups first. It's irrelevant to his randomization test, however important it might be for formulating a parametric model.)

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Would you be willing to post this as an answer?

Well, rather than answering "How would Fisher choose sample sizes?", I thought I was providing some background on why he didn't try & follow the Neyman-Pearson approach in some circumstances, viz those in which he'd consider a test.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica But you also brought up "sensitivity/sensitiveness" and the lady-tasting-tea experiment in The Design of Experiments. Together, this does answer "How would Fisher choose n?" It's a concrete example where Fisher himself discusses the role of sample size; and so it's the most direct answer given (so far) to the question I was trying to pose. Michael Lew's answer is very helpful too, but "See Fisher's note about sensitiveness in TDoE" is basically the answer I'd like to accept (along with your further comments).

Summary: In the one known written example of Fisher choosing a sample size, he chose a size that would allow a chosen value of the statistic to count as significant evidence. That's how he could choose a sample size without specifying a particular alternative-hypothesis parameter value, which would be needed for Neyman-Pearson power calculations.

Thanks to comments by @Scortchi (*) for pointing out Fisher's notion of "sensitivity" or "sensitiveness" and his concrete example in The Design of Experiments. I have the 8th ed of TDoE; on pages 21-22 Fisher introduces (but doesn't rigorously define) "the sensitiveness of an experiment" and explicitly discusses the role of sample size in designing his lady-tasting-tea experiment.
(This is an entirely different usage than in "sensitivity vs specificity" or "sensitivity analysis".)
Fisher's "sensitiveness" sounds a little like power curves, either with respect to increasing sample size or with respect to repeating the experiment many times. From TDoE:

...an experiment with 12 cups, six of each kind, gives, on the null hypothesis, 1 chance in 924 for complete success, and 36 chances for 5 of each kind classified right and 1 wrong. As 37 is less than a twentieth of 924, such a test could be counted as significant, although a pair of cups have been wrongly classified; and it is easy to verify that, using larger numbers still, a significant result could be obtained with a still higher proportion of errors. By increasing the size of the experiment, we can render it more sensitive, meaning by this that it will allow of the detection of a lower degree of sensory discrimination, or, in other words, of a quantitatively smaller departure from the null hypothesis.

However, unlike power curves, Fisher's "quantitatively smaller departure from the null hypothesis" seems to be about statistics, not parameters. His example is about increasing $n$ to allow for more mistakes by the lady tasting tea and still reach significance (i.e., get a low p-value). So he's increasing $n$ to allow a larger range of statistics to count as evidence against $H_0$, without ever specifying an explicit alternative parameter value / $H_A$. In other words, unlike Neyman-Pearson's approach, he does not pin down a particular $H_A$ and then find the distribution of p-values under $H_A$, so it's impossible to calculate power as such. As @Scortchi writes,

F. introduces no statistical model of gradations in the subject's ability to discriminate; so there's no question of calculating the power of his test when any particular alternative hypothesis to 'no ability whatsoever' is true, except 'an infallible ability' ... the analysis also nicely illustrates his assertion that researchers can often be quite sure that their test statistic adequately measures discrepancy with the null while having only a foggy notion of alternatives.

Later in TDoE, Fisher continues to mention "sensitiveness" but in the context of qualitative aspects of study design, e.g. whether or not to use blocking. I have not found any other writings where Fisher discusses the quantitative choice of sample size.
Finally, Fisher's tea-tasting example is about a discrete response variable (each guess is either correct or incorrect), so it's possible to enumerate the sample space and count how many distinct ways the results could be statistically significant. If your gut says "I don't mind if the lady tasting tea makes X mistakes," you can figure out how many cups need to be tasted to ensure that X mistakes would still count as significant. But it's not obvious to me if this can always be generalized for a continuous response variable.
Jose Perezgonzalez has written about "sensitiveness" more broadly, citing Fisher. See for instance the preprint "Statistical Sensitiveness for the Behavioral Sciences" (2017). But it's not clear to me whether it's exactly the same as Fisher's idea, since Fisher didn't give an explicit definition.  Perezgonzalez seems to focus on finding the smallest sample size for which a chosen value of the sample statistic (i.e. the observed effect size) would be significant. If I'm reading it right, he also talks about finding the probability that the sample statistic is large enough to be "convincing" rather than the prob. that the p-value is below some $\alpha$... but you still need to specify a particular $H_A$ (or average over a specific mix of $H_A$'s, as his simulations seem to do) in order to find these probabilities.

(*) I asked @Scortchi if they could write up their comments as an answer, but they have not done so in the past week. Based on the etiquette recommended here and here, I am writing up this answer myself---not to get the rep, but just so that it does not remain an unanswered question.

(+1) I've had a busy week, & am of course quite happy for you to have used my comments as a jumping off point.

Another angle is that, since the early days, Fisher argued that inference about a parameter in a statistical model was best framed as a problem of estimation rather than of hypothesis testing. Though I don't recall his discussing choice of sample size in this case, the variance ('precision') of a point estimate, or the width of a confidence interval ('fiducial distribution') would be what matttered.

@Scortchi Thank you! And I agree that precision or CI width are often a more useful way to think about the problem than hypothesis testing. I'd be curious to read more about this from Fisher's perspective. More recently, Kelley and Maxwell have written (for instance here and here) about choosing the sample size to achieve a desired CI width; they call it accuracy in parameter estimation (AIPE).

This may be more of an extended comment than a fully fleshed out answer, but where you write that "Fisher imagines repeating the same experiment", I feel that you have missed an important issue. Fisher did actually repeat experiments. He ran agricultural experiments in thoughtfully modified forms over years and so when he went to design an experiment or to analyse the results he had relevant experience to call upon. When he writes of an experiment that rarely fails ... he is not talking about imaginary experiments!
There is a difference between what Fisher tried to do (and teach) and what we now tend to assume he must have meant with our all-or-none 'significant' minds. When we talk about experimental design there is a tendency to assume that (i) the experiment has to stand alone and (ii) we really only have guesses about means and variances to go on. For Fisher, a scientist can call on more than that, and any conclusions were only provisionally accepted. Some were more firmly provisionally accepted than others, but nonetheless the idea that inferences would be subject to change on the basis of subsequent results was key to his approach. That is why (one of the reasons, I suppose) he became so adamantly opposed to the all-or-none accept/reject outcomes of Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis tests.
His (Fisher's) prescriptions often lacked the specificity of the recipes that fall out of a Neyman–Pearsonian approach but, using the principle of charity, I would say that that is his attempt at communicating a framework that is well suited to a thoughtful scientific endeavour.
What would Fisher do instead of a pre-experiment power analysis? I'm not sure that he says anywhere. I've read a lot of his work, but the material on power that I recall was mostly about how he denies the reality of an alternative hypothesis, which implicitly denies the utility of a pre-experiment power analysis. No alternative, no power analysis. However, it is quite possible, in my opinion, that a good part of that denial was fuelled by his feud with Neyman. I think of it as a reluctance to accept its utility rather than a recognition of its incompatibility with scientific research.
What should Fisher do instead of a power analysis? Well, given his reluctance to rely on a specified alternative hypothesis, a curve of power versus effect size might have been acceptable as a tool for experimental design. I suspect that he might have preferred a curve of the expected p-values instead of power curves. I've written about those curves in some detail in section 2 of this chapter: A reckless Guide to P-Values.

"a good part of that denial was fuelled by his feud with Neyman" -- I think you are right! Thanks as well for suggesting the curve of expected p-values. I will read your article!
