# The product distribution: how fast does dissimilarity increase as a function of number of samples?

Tags: probability, distance, approximation, bounds

If $\mathcal{D}$ is a distribution, let $\mathcal{D}^n$ denote the $n$-fold Cartesian product of $\mathcal{D}$.  In other words, $\mathcal{D}^n$ is the distribution of $n$-tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ where each $x_i$ is drawn iid from $\mathcal{D}$.

If $\mathcal{D},\mathcal{D}'$ are two distributions, let $d(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{D}')$ denote a dissimilarity measure; it measures how different the two distributions are.  For instance, we might use the $\ell_1$ distance measure (i.e., $||\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{D}'||_1$, aka total variation distance), the $\ell_2$ distance (i.e., $||\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{D}'||_2$), the $\ell_\infty$ distance (i.e., $||\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{D}'||_\infty$), the KL divergence ($D_\textrm{KL}(\mathcal{D} || \mathcal{D}')$), or something else entirely.  Often we might expect these to be normalized so that the dissimilarity is between 0 and 1, but I suppose that's not necessary.

Let $\mathcal{D}_0,\mathcal{D}_1$ be two distributions, and $d_1,d_2$  any two dissimilarity measures (maybe the same one, maybe different).
Are there any bounds, estimates, approximations, or rules of thumb that relate $d_2(\mathcal{D}_0^n,\mathcal{D}_1^n)$ to $d_1(\mathcal{D}_0,\mathcal{D}_1)$?

Comment: One application of this: hypothesis testing when you have many samples from either $\mathcal{D}_0$ or $\mathcal{D}_1$ (and you want to determine which).  See also [Hypothesis testing and total variation distance vs. Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17300/2921) and also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23978/2921).